WPF - Drawing a filled polygon in a DrawingContext
Is there an "easy" way to draw, say, a filled hexagon in a DrawingContext?
Or is the answer, "That's why DrawingContext has a DrawGeometry method"?

That is the answer...

Question answered by Clemens in a comment to the question
